Integrating Distinct Color Info From binocular vision?
Are humans capable of learning to integrate different color information from their two eyes?
If someone wore glasses all the time with different filters on left/right eyes (eg a red suppressing filter on left and green suppressing on right would you eventually be able to recognize where your eyes were reporting different colors (without blinking one eye) and thereby distinguish otherwise indistinguishable red and green signals.
Or could a non-colorblind person gain an extra color channel this way (perhaps at the cost of some degradation in binocular 3d clues)
--
I did a brief search and found some articles about processing such signals as luster in individuals who haven't tried to accommodate to such glasses but it didn't tell me what happens if you wear such glasses for months.
